# Does the expression "taking a cut" imply some sort of grift? If so, what's a neutral equivalent expression?

Tags: expressions, connotations

Does the expression "taking a cut" (to mean taking some financial commission) imply some sort of grift, or is it neutral? If it implies some sort of grift, what would be a neutral equivalent expression?

Usage example:

> When an academic researcher receives a gift funding from an industry partner, does the academic researcher's university **take a cut**, or does the academic researcher receives the entire gift funding?

Comment: it would be "receive", not "receives" but otherwise I would find it a correct and reasonably neutral sentence. In this context "takes a cut" doesn't imply anything illegal, immoral or unethical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Take a cut" is relatively neutral and doesn't imply that anyone is acting illegally or improperly, though it is rarely a postive thing to say.

> I work through a job agency, so I know that they take a cut of everything I earn.

The agency isn't acting improperly, there is no grift involved.